# $Sup \int |f_{n}|^{1+\epsilon } d\mu < \infty$ for every $\epsilon$ implies $\{f_{n}\}$ is uniformly integrable.

Tags: measure-theory

How can I prove that in a probability space, if $\{f_{n}\}$ is such that 
\begin{align*}
\mbox{sup   }_{n} \int |f_{n}|^{1+\epsilon} d\mu < \infty
\end{align*}
for every $\epsilon > 0$ then $\{f_{n}\}$ is uniformly integrable?
Definition of uniformly integrable  is 
\begin{align*}
\mbox{lim }_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \left( \mbox{ sup }_{n} \int_{|f_{n}| >\alpha} |f_{n}| d\mu \right)=0
\end{align*}

I am not understanding in which direction I should think with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $$M = \sup_n \int |f_n|^{1+\epsilon} \, d\mu < \infty.$$

Let $\alpha > 0$. For every $n$ you have
$$\int_{|f_n| > \alpha} |f_n| \, d\mu \le \int_{|f_n| > \alpha} \frac{|f_n|^{1+\epsilon}}{\alpha^\epsilon} \, d\mu \le \frac{1}{\alpha^\epsilon} \int |f_n|^{1+\epsilon} \, d\mu$$ so that $$\sup_n \int_{|f_n| > \alpha} |f_n| \, d\mu \le \frac{M}{\alpha^\epsilon}.$$

Now let $\alpha \to \infty$.